# How do I read gdf file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to read the gdf file using this code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import mne
raw=mne.io.read_raw_gdf("eeg.gdf")
```

I got this error:

```
index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

I replaced the file name with complete path: `r"C:\Files\Python\eb.gdf"`
I also wrote the path without `r`, with `/` and `\\`. But none of them worked!

The file (eeg.gdf) contains some data and it is not empty.
How can I fix this problem?

I expect to be able to read the file.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I changed the code as you suggest. I got this error "module 'neo.io' has no attribute 'gdfio'."

Comment: understand. so, you are certain the file isn't empty and the file is in the location defined in your script. do you the have necessary permissions to access the file? Also, if the file is open, close it before you try to access it with your script. you can check if the file is in defined location like this, if os.path.isfile(file_path): print("File exists").